# How to save the stack in the AVR architecture?

Tags: arduino, stack, avr

I am writing a scheduler for the Arduino UNO (based on the Atmel ATmega 328p) but I am coming from x86 and I have no idea on how to save the stack on a context switch so it can later be restored when returning to the task.

Can someone please explain how to do this?

Comment: There are a bunch of open source RTOSes for AVR out there, you should look at one.  Also, I think this question is too broad because you haven't given any indication which part of the task is giving you difficulty.  For example, do you know how to compile and run assembly code?  Do you know how the AVR's stack pointer works?  Do you know how to copy data from the stack to somewhere else and change the stack pointer?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to "save the stack" in a context switch.

Instead, you want to save the state of the processor to the stack, and then change the stack pointer to a different stack and restore the context from there.

The relevant data for the state of the processor is the SP, PC, STATUS register, and all the gpio registers.

The PC is pushed onto the stack with the call to your switching function. You save the SP somewhere so that you can load it later. That means you only need to push the STATUS register and the 32 gpio registers onto the stack.

Each task needs its own stack and variable to hold the SP. You can keep these in an array of structures.

Answer (score -1):

All I did was hit google for Arduino stack dump and got this:

[How do I dump my stack in Arduino?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691864/how-do-i-dump-my-stack-in-arduino)

Here's the code form that link since they don't like links even to their own site.

```
uint8_t stackArray[30];
void createStackDump() 
{
  volatile uint8_t* mSP = (uint8_t*)SP;

  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) 
  {
    stackArray[i] = *mSP;
    mSP++;
  }
}
```